# The command "platforms\android\cordova\clean.bat" exited with code 2

Tags: apache, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

While am debug my solution in Visual Studio 2015 Cordova this issue occured The command "platforms\android\cordova\clean.bat" exited with code 2.

Comment: Did you got the right answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015, Menu: **Tools => Options => Tools for Apache Cordova => Environment Variable Overrides** set the correct ADT_HOME and JAVA_HOME.

Also *Clean Cordova cache* from the **Cordova Tools**. Then open and debug your project.

Comment: Also make sure you have the appropriate/latest Android SDK Platform-tools and Build-tools

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work until I deleted the `platforms\android\folder` too

Answer (score 1):

I ended in a similar issue when I installed the VS.Net2015 and tried to create a blank Cordova project and compile. I did try a lot of different things including reinstalling Android Studio and VS but none helped.

Finally what it boiled down to was that I had a 64Bit OS an installed a 32bit JDK which somehow didn't work well together. Downloaded the 64Bit JDK and corrected the Path in visual studio and now its working.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to it and fixed my issue.

Problem is you got set the Enviromnent path in your system properly

1 . Make sure you install JAVA and ANT
2 . Make sure you set the JAVA_HOME AND ANT_HOME along with the updated PATH in the System variable.

Restart your studio. this issue would be gone. njoy. :)

Comment: Maybe you should specify what exactly should be put in the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and resolved it today as follows:

> 1. Check cmd > java -d64 -version - JVM had error
> 2. Installed Java from java.com/en/download
> 3. Restarted PC
> 4. Check cmd > java -d64 -version - no error
> 5. Delete ..\bin\platforms\android folder {android was the platform for which I had the issue}
> 6. Clean Solution & Build Solution

Successfully deployed to Device now!

Answer (score 0):

That error message unfortunately isn't very helpful. When I ran into this error, I was able to get more information by simply running that clean.bat file in a command prompt so I could see the actual error message. The path to the bat file is in the error message: "platforms\android\cordova\clean.bat".

For me it was simply that the path to my keystore file was incorrect in my build.json file. After I fixed that the clean worked fine.